# How to create a database in Android system using PHP script?

Tags: php, android

I have created web application that is also converted to APK. My instructors required me to have an offline feature for the application in Android. How could I actually create an offline database on the Android system using PHP? I had researched on doing this and I found that SQLite3 is the best database but I don't know how to implement, install it on Android or actually create a simple database. Thanks for your consideration and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQLite` is a opensource SQL database that stores data to a text file on a device. Android comes in with built in `SQLite` database implementation so you don't need to do any installation.

The answer of this question is slightly broad, I suggest you to take a look on this tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm).

Comment: I created the website web based. So how am I supposed to do that? Please help me :/

Comment: On as by your question, I'm assuming that u have create app using webview which is showing website in the android app, if I'm correct please let me know. And again please tell me in detail what u want.

Comment: Yes. Your assumption is correct. What I want is to make an online and offline functionality for my webview developed android app. Which I want to make a database for an offline use and an online database for online usage as well. For the user could access some functions without an internet connection.

Comment: You have to create a local `html` page when there is no internet, because webview will not load without internet. So first you have to create local html page(same html page of website and save in text file in android). Load the html text file when no internet and write functionality with SQlite. A good example is the link i given u. look here also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717851/android-load-sqlite-database-content-to-webview

Answer (score 0):

Your Teacher might meant, you should make your application integrated with external Database.
Which means, you should be making getting data from internet and sending to internet.
i.e. you need a server, on which using PHP script you should get you query which in further gets data from an DB ( Mysql etc) .
You might be interested in this tutorial. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: I didn't build the application natively. I created it in a web frame work. How should I possibly do that?